Why is the Themes tab not showing in QWC2's Admin GUI?
I'm installing QWC2 for the first time, following the 20.12.2024 guide and using qwc-services as suggested. After reading the Themes page, I wasn't sure about the intended way to publish projects for end users. I found a 3-year-old YouTube video that showed publishing through the Themes tab in QWC Admin.
However, in my new installation, the Themes tab is absent, as shown in this screenshot:

Assuming it might be the Themes plugin, I followed the instructions on the GitHub page to enable it. Here’s the relevant part of my tenantConfig.json inside adminGui (I have not changed the default folder structure):
"config": {
    "db_url": "postgresql:///?service=qwc_configdb",
    "config_generator_service_url": "http://qwc-config-service:9090",
    "totp_enabled": false,
    "user_info_fields": [],
    "proxy_url_whitelist": [],
    "proxy_timeout": 60,
    "plugins": ["themes"],
    "input_config_path": "/volumes/config-in",
    "qwc2_path": "/qwc2/",
    "qgs_resources_path": "/qgs-resources",
    "info_templates_path": "/volumes/info-templates",
    "ows_prefix": "/ows",
    "default_qgis_server_url": "http://localhost:80/ows",
    "ows_service_url": "/ows"
}

Despite this, the Themes tab still doesn't appear. Is this the intended way of publishing, or has it changed in the latest versions?
